# Performing HTTP Post request in "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" action using AFNetworking Library

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to write an authentication module for my application. I want to check whether the user is saved before or not. For this purpose, I have to check my database whether this user is saved before or not.

I'm planning to make an HTTP request to my server backend. Thus, I made a sample server side request to the server as given below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [identifier isEqualToString:@"login"]){

        NSString *curUrl = [self.serverUrl stringByAppendingString:@"/test"];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
        [manager POST:curUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        return YES;
    }else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"signup"]) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

However, I'm facing an exception as given below:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[AFHTTPRequestOperation initWithRequest:],
 /myproj/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m:164
2013-11-11 09:17:17.005 myproj[354:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: urlRequest'
*** First throw call stack:

(0x2eb05f53 0x38edc6af 0x2eb05e2d 0x2f4ad183 0x1a3d15 0x19cb17 0x19f3ad 0x19fb31 0xb7565 
0x3127b603 0x3127b3c1 0x31325637 0x31361d7b 0x313606b3 0x3135f705 0x3153a65b 0x312abf3f 
0x312abedf 0x312abeb9 0x31297b3f 0x312ab92f 0x312ab601 0x312a668d 0x3127ba25 0x3127a221 
0x2ead118b 0x2ead065b 0x2eacee4f 0x2ea39ce7 0x2ea39acb 0x3375a283 0x312dba41 0xb87a5 
0x393e4ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why do I getting this error? Does HTTP Post request for AFNetworking is asynchronous?

Comment: Method POST:parameters:success:failure: is asynchronous. It invokes success or failure block after execution is ended in background thread (under the hood it create AFURLConnectionOperation which runs in background operation queue).

Comment: How can I make a synchronous HTTP request?

Comment: I think you don't need synchronous request. Synchronous operation will block main thread and UI will become freezed. The best practice is to show pre-loader (something like MBProgressHUD) while your request is executing and hide it when the request is finished.

Comment: Ok. However, the code throws the exception(the full exception is also given in the question above": "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: urlRequest' " How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your problem with "NSInternalInconsistencyException" we can take a look at AFHTTPRequestOperationManager implementation:
[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST:parameters:success:failure: method source code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m#L150)

It is constructing result URLString with self.baseURL. You already constructed this, so the result url is incorrect. To fix this exception try to change your url construction code:

```
NSString *curUrl = @"/test";
```

or:

```
NSString *curUrl = @"test";
```

Comment: ankakusu, no problem :) Please, accept answer to this question, if your problem is solved.

Comment: Opedge, well I realised that the problem was at the next segue. That code snippet works fine but at the next segue, there was a bug. However, still thank you for your reply.